# Creating a method that returns value from an API using Await/Async

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a method that returns a value from the API. How do I implement the Async/ Await?

```
getAccountById(){
        let accountName;
        this.accountService.accountSelect(`SELECT * FROM account WHERE accountId = ${ localStorage.getItem('accountId') } AND accountArchived = 0`).subscribe(async (res: account) => {
          accountName = await res[0]['accountLastName'];
        });
        return accountName;
      }


    console.log(getAccountById()); //undefined
```

Comment: You are anyways using `subscribe`, which will only emit when there is any data arrived. I don't understand, why do you want async/await?

Comment: You have to `await` the call to `accountSelect`, which means `getAccountById` also needs to be `async`. Even then, calling `getAccountById` would return a *promise*, not a value. I'd recommend reading up on asynchronous JavaScript, and learning about the observables (not promises) that underpin much of Angular.

Comment: how can I implement it? I am just new.

Comment: `async/await ` is for function that return a `Promise`, not an `Observable`

Answer (score 0):

async/await is used in case of `Promises` to reduce the callback hell. In case of observables, you have to subscribe to get the value. Hence async/await cannot be used. You could use `axios` or `isomorphic fetch` instead of HttpClient if you want to use promise based requests. In that case you can use `await` to get the response object into a varible inside some `async` function

Comment: getAccountById(){
        let accountName;
        this.accountService.accountSelect(`SELECT * FROM account WHERE accountId = ${ localStorage.getItem('accountId') } AND accountArchived = 0`).subscribe((res: account) => {
          accountName = res[0]['accountLastName'];
        });
        return accountName;
      }

Comment: Why whenever i call this function withour async/ await, the result is undefined? console.log(this.getAccountById);

Comment: The result is undefined because the line is executed synchronously whereas the data is retrieved at a later stage. You should console.log inside the subscription to get that to execute when the data actually is retrieved. Async/await is just a sugarcoat syntax that waits for the promise to resolve before proceeding further.

Comment: Consider this, you ask your friend to give you some water. He goes to the kitchen to fetch a glass of water. If you try to console.log your state (or, drink water from your hand) at this time, it wont work since your hand is empty. You should wait until he returns and gives you the glass before drinking. In async/await, the await does this "waiting" so that the code looks synchronous though it is actually executing after the promise resolves.

Comment: how ca I resolve it? I do not know how to use the async/ await

Comment: you don't have to use async/await. Use the function inside subscribe to do your changes.

Comment: This is an XY Problem. You are trying to solve X through Y whereas Y is not exactly needed to solve X. Give your actual use-case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you want to change implementation like this :

```
getAccountById() {
 return this.accountService.accountSelect(`SELECT * FROM account WHERE accountId = ${ localStorage.getItem('accountId') } AND accountArchived = 0`);
 }
...
getAccountById().subscribe(value=>{
 console.log(value);
 })
```